# How do I install Neovim with GUI and msgpack support in Ubuntu?

Tags: neovim, installing, neovim-qt, linux-ubuntu

I would like to get Neovim because of its msgpack API and clear roadmap of development, but it is not in Ubuntu 16.04's repositories.

```
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim' (main)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gtk3' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gnome' (main)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-athena' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-nox-py2' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gtk-py2' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-nox' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gtk3-py2' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gnome-py2' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-tiny' (main)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gtk' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-athena-py2' (universe)
```

I have now selected vim-gtk3 but it may limit me later.

---

How do I get graphical Neovim with msgpack support?

Comment: Posted how to get neovim installed since you initially made that comment. However, your question is vague. What do you want to have access to that would be covered in "sufficient api for programming"?

Comment: @jecxjo Sufficient stereotyping where I have challenges to get anything to work.

Comment: GVim or Neovim? Please be specific.

Comment: @muru I mean graphical neovim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instructions can be found on the [Neovim Wiki](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim)

As of the posting of this answer, the site's current instructions are as follows:

### Ubuntu

Neovim has been added to a [Personal Package Archive](https://launchpad.net/~neovim-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/unstable) which allows you to install it using `apt-get` on Ubuntu [12.04 and later](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

To be able to use **add-apt-repository** you may need to install software-properties-common:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

If you're using an older version Ubuntu you have to use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install neovim
```

Prerequisites for the Python modules:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip python3-dev python3-pip
```

If you're using an older version Ubuntu you have to use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip python3-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

For instructions on how to install the Python modules, see [`:help nvim_python`](http://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_python.html).

If you want to use Neovim for some (or all) of the editor alternatives, use the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi /usr/bin/nvim 60
sudo update-alternatives --config vi
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vim vim /usr/bin/nvim 60
sudo update-alternatives --config vim
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/nvim 60
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

Note, however, that special interfaces, like `view` for `nvim -R`, are not supported.  (See [#1646](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1646) and [#2008](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/2008).)

---

The GUI portion needs to be installed separately. See the [list of 3rd party GUIs](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Related-projects) on the Neovim site.

Comment: Are there are list of those views in practice? It would be nice to visualise all those views.

Comment: I installed all those things suitable for Ubuntu 16.04. I cannot reach those tools in terminal by `gvim`/`gnvim`. I purged `vim-gtk3` afterwards installing the things. How can you reach gnvim?